# BlackBerry Web-service call parameter encoding

Tags: asp.net, web-services, blackberry, soap

I have used the Java Sun Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 to generate method stubs for my SOAP webservice. I have been using this for a while and it works great. I now need to add support for the French language. When I send up a string like '**pièce**' as one of the properties on an object, it turns into '**pi??ce**' by the time it is read by the server. Obviously, the encoding is off somewhere, but I can't see anywhere that I can change the way the generated stub encodes the parameters passed to the web service. Any suggestions?

Update: Here is the header and the start of the xml sent from the BlackBerry:

```
POST /website/service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
Via: MDS_4.1.5.26
Content-Length: 2257
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Language: en-US
Accept: */*
Host: host
User-Agent: RIM JSR172/1.0
SOAPAction: "http://www.test.com/Test"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Here is the header and the start of the xml sent from the iPhone (which works):

```
POST /website/service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2359
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr-fr
Host: host
User-Agent: wsdl2objc
Soapaction: http://www.test.com/Test

<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Comment: are you sure it is getting mangled on the client side, or is it possibly getting mangled on the server side?

Comment: I am not 100% positive, but I have an iPhone client hitting the same web service and everything is sent and received correctly. Which has led me to assume the problem is on the BlackBerry side.

Comment: Using UTF-8 on both side would be a nice idea.

Comment: Yes, it would. As I state in the question I can't see where to set that (or to make sure it is set correctly) on the BlackBerry side.

Comment: Can you just add the Content-Type by your self ?

Comment: On the BlackBerry side I don't have access to the code that sets the Content-Type.

Comment: It's certainly possible to set the content-type using the api's in the BlackBerry sdk, can you explain the restrictions you are under on the BB client?

Comment: As I mention in the question, I am using the wireless toolkit, which generates the code that consumes the web service. Their generated code is using the javax.microedition.xml.rpc.Operation class to invoke the remote method. Inside the invoke method is where the HttpConnection is created and the properties are set on it. I don't have any access to this code and there aren't any properties that I can set that will affect how it sets the content-type.

Comment: Sorry that was unobservant of me, but it sounds like you're stuffed as far as using JSWT goes? I can only think of one craaaazy workaround which is to modify the API to accept the french text payload as a soap attachment. I'll get my coat...

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking I'll have to do something on the server side to handle both of these requests. Any suggestions on that front?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Unicode BOM](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceOfBeingUTF8.aspx)? I'd check the packet sniffer. As it may not be the content-type but rather the bytes themselves.